# intro.js - add shift + ? keyboard hotkey / shortcut support to launch (or trigger) introJs().start()

Tags: javascript, dom-events, key-bindings, intro.js

How do I make mousetrap launch intro.js guided tour?

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> will ... `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="startIntro();">launch tour</a>`

Comment: please excuse my question, i found the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I used to achieve results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Mousetrap.bind(["?"], function(e) {
    startIntro();
});
</script>
```

- source 1 = http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/using-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javascript
- source 2 = https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/